# Angularjs: Why data fetched by service query is treated like object and won't be used by Angular

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my service (factory) I do a query to fetch the data from my server PHP page.
Two scenarios:

1. If I provide an array by calling a function (which returns the array) and then echo json_encode($data); at the bottom, Angular will complain about resource misconfiguration (something like the data being of a wrong type, object instead of array, or vice-versa, I would say based on whether I have set isArray true or false);
2. If I create an array of the same structure and comment out other code, leaving just the echo json_encode($data); at the bottom, the damned thing will use that data!

What surprises me most - if I open 2 tabs, and print_r or var_dump both array types, they will be exactly the same!

```
// I call my function to retrieve Google Plus posts like this
// in my response.php file which is being called for data
$pluses = $serviceObj->loadActivities($uId);

// That method creates then returns the resulting array
// note that I have to reach deeper into the response to take out just the 
// level i'm interested in - that is "items". 
// I used $key here to make sure each post is numerically indexed
// and I don't think that is the culprit but who knows..

public function loadActivities($uId)
{
    $items = array();
    $response = $this->service->activities->listActivities($uId, 'public', array('maxResults'=>4));
    foreach($response['modelData']['items'] as $key => $item){
        $items[$key]['displayName'] = $item['actor']['displayName'];
        $d = new \DateTime($item['published']);
        $items[$key]['publishedDate'] = $d->format("n/j/Y");
        $items[$key]['publishedMonth'] = $d->format("F");
        $items[$key]['imageSrc'] = $item['object']['attachments'][0]['image']['url'];
        $items[$key]['content'] = $item['object']['content'];
    }

    return $items;
}

// Now, this array looks like this when I do print_r on it
$arr = array(
    0 => array(
        'displayName' => 'thevalue',
        'publishedDate' => 'thevalue',
        'publishedMonth' => 'thevalue',
        'imageSrc' => 'thevalue',
        'content' => 'thevalue'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'displayName' => 'thevalue',
        'publishedDate' => 'thevalue',
        'publishedMonth' => 'thevalue',
        'imageSrc' => 'thevalue',
        'content' => 'thevalue'
    ),
    ....
);

// at the bottom of the file, there is this
echo json_encode($arr);
// so that Angularjs can get the data. This does not work (the error 
// at the bottom of this question is triggered
```

I even tried moving my manually typed array from the PHP page into my function which returns the array in the case 1 above - and then return that array (I did this to test the very same array) - still error!

```
// so basically, if I manually type the same array but directly in 
// the response.php file, that is, the array is no longer returned by the function,
// and then
echo json_encode($arr);
// at the bottom, Angularjs stops complaining and consumes it.
```

My service

```
angular.module('socialPosts.services', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('PostsResource', ['$resource', function($resource){
            return $resource('response.php', {}, {
                query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true }
            })
    }])
;
```

My controller

```
angular.module('socialPosts.controllers', [])
    .controller('LoadPostsCtrl', ['$scope', 'PostsResource', function($scope, PostsResource){
            $scope.init = function(network, ename){
                $scope.entry = ename;
                $scope.loadTabContent(network);
            };
            $scope.content = [];
            $scope.loadTabContent = function(called){
                $scope.networkCalled = called;
                $scope.content = PostsResource.query( {from: $scope.networkCalled, company: $scope.entry } ).$promise.then(
                        function(result){
                                $scope.content = result;
                        },
                        function(error){
                            alert(error);
                        }
                    );
            };
    }]);
```

I have no choice but to assume this has something to do with the fact the data was obtained via a function call because in any case I am getting data from my server (PHP page).

Actual error:

> Error: $resource:badcfg
>   Response does not match configured parameter
>   Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an array but got an object
>   Description
>   This error occurs when the $resource service expects a response that can be deserialized as an array, receives an object, or vice versa. By default, all resource actions expect objects, except query which expects arrays.
>
> To resolve this error, make sure your $resource configuration matches the actual format of the data returned from the server.

For more information, see the $resource API reference documentation.

Comment: This is a common error with PHP and has to do with the fact that PHP may choose to interprete an object wither as an associative array (object) or indexed array (array), based on the type and values of its keys. Your `$resource` request expects either an JSON encoded array or a JSON encoded object, but PHP is not returning it in that format (i.e. it chooses to encode the "thing" as associative array instead of indexed array (which results in a JSON encoded object instead of JSON encoded array) or vice versa). Showing some code might lead to the exact problem and solution.

Comment: @ExpertSystem Alright, I just added some chunks of code that may shed some light on what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird as it looked, it turned out something that was supposed to help was actually the culprit. After commenting out line

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

result array returned by the function worked!